# pygame.display.update() not working properly on threading

Tags: python

I am making a game for my school project with pygame. I want to use another thread (excluding the main thread) to run `pygame.display.update()` to update the screen of my game.

Here is the code:

```py
def display_update():
    while running: # running is declared before as True for the game loop 
        pygame.display.update()

dis  = Thread(target=display_update)
dis.start()
```

However, after the code runs the images in the screen are flickering.

Comment: Why do you want another thread, It will likely over complicate the code and it does not seem like there is any benefit.

Comment: Don't use threads. Pygame will create threads when necessary (for example for the mixer). You are most likely going to run into troubles as pygame has restrictions one what can run on certain threads. Also, your example will definitely create problems for you. `pygame.display.update()` should only be called once per frame, not as fast as possible in a separate thread. You game will be **much** slower than single-threaded, have way more bugs, be non-deterministic, use more memory, and so on... There's no benefit for using threads in your example, just drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

***You shouldn't use threads like this since pygame can easily be updated in the main thread and using threads with pygame can cause undefined behaviour***

The problem is that the threads aren't synced. If it is absolutely necessary to use threads, then something like this should work:

```
running = True
do_update = False


def display_update():
    while running: # running is declared before as True for the game loop 
       if do_update:
           pygame.display.update()
           do_update = False

dis  = Thread(target=display_update)
dis.start() 

while running:
    if not do_update:
        #Code
        #Code
        #Code
    do_update = True
```

This basically stops the main thread while `display_update` updates the screen.

A better way to code this would be:

```
while running:
    #Code
    #Code
    #Code
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: @SabyasachiMitra Don't use multi-threading unless you know the restrictions and complications of them, especially with pygame. Pygame is built on SDL2 and has restrictions on what can be run on other threads than the main thread. For example, polling for events should only be done in the main thread. Updating the display should happen in the thread where the display was created. There are many things to consider and while it might look like it worked, there's a risk you'll end up with weird and hard-to-find bugs down the line.

Comment: @SabyasachiMitra @Yash Also, this code has other problem. `display_update` is eating CPU by just checking for the `do_update` to become `True`. There's also a data race for the variable `do_update`, which might not cause any major issues in this example, but is definitely something that could be an issue down the line.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Yes I did mention that in the question comments and I will mention it in my answer as well I think op had to use threads because of his assignment

Comment: Although, the problem isn't that _"pygame can easily be updated in the main thread"._ The problem is that pygame can't handle certain things in other threads, and doing so is undefined behavior. Events must be handle in the main thread, and graphics should be done on the thread where the video module is initialized. So it's not just that there are drawbacks such as complexity, memory consumption, bad CPU utilization, data races, and so on, but also that pygame (and the underlying SDL2 and OS) doesn't guarantee that the program will be correct. It might by chance, but can break at any time

Answer (score 0):

Don't use threads. Pygame is built on SDL2 and has restrictions on what can be run on other threads than the main thread. For example, polling for events should only be done in the main thread. Updating the display should happen in the thread where the display was created. There are many things to consider and while it might look like it worked, there's a risk you'll end up with weird and hard-to-find bugs down the line.

Pygame will create threads when necessary (for example for the mixer). Your example will definitely create problems for you. `pygame.display.update()` should only be called once per frame, not as fast as possible in a separate thread. You game will be much slower than single-threaded, have way more bugs, be non-deterministic, use more memory, and so on... There's no benefit for using threads in your example, just drawbacks.

Do it sequentially, as it'll be faster, take less memory, be easier to debug, easier to reason about, and most importantly, it'll work without any unexpected behavior.

```
running = True
while running:
    # Handle timing

    # Handle events    

    # Update objects

    # Draw/blit to screen.

    pygame.display.update()  # Called only once per frame.
```

#### Disclaimer

There are situation where threads are useful, for example doing asynchronous I/O-tasks (like loading assets, fetching/sending network packets) or maybe for parallel computation. But then you have to consider and pay for all the complications that comes with it, like synchronize shared data and design around asynchronous and non-deterministic execution.